# How to find a specific computer slowing down the internet connection

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection, internet-speed

I am working in a factory having about 100 PCs on the same network.
The internet speed is very slow and I was wondering if there is any tool to find the computer slowing down the internet speed.
I think this is caused by a specific computer since before the employees turn on their PC in the morning, the speed is very good.

Comment: Another advice would be sending an e-mail to all employees to stop downloading movies, tv series and other stuff from the company's internet. If it does not stop, get some filtering for the websites and block all websites that may contain torrents or magnet links.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the router or gateway that they all connect to?

Home routers often have traffic monitoring functionality which can give you data on machines and content that they are accessing.

If it is a server then you would have to give more information to the setup? But
you probably want to use something like MRTG (free) http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

Can you install any software on it for example?

Or you could start a harsher approach and just block all sites that aren't work related...

Comment: there is also the possibility that all computers together generate traffic that slows down the network not just one.

Comment: Well yes, it's also possible you don't have the bandwidth to support 100PCs even doing normal work.